# How to catch all unhandled exceptions (i.e. without existing @ExceptionHandler) in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to let HandlerExceptionResolver resolve any Exceptions that I don't explicit catch via  `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

Anyways, I want to apply specific logic on those exceptions. Eg send a mail notification or log additionally. I can achieve this by adding a `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` catch as follows:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public MyExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Object io(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        return ...
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public Object exception(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        MailService.send();
        Logger.logInSpecificWay();

        //TODO how to continue in the "normal" spring way with HandlerExceptionResolver?
    }
}
```

Problem: if I add `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` like that, I can catch those unhandled exceptions.

**BUT** I cannot let `spring` continue the normal workflow with `HandlerExceptionResolver` to create the response `ModelAndView` and set a HTTP STATUS code automatically.

Eg if someone tries a `POST` on a `GET` method, spring by default would return a `405 Method not allowed`. But with an `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` I would swallow this standard handling of spring...

So how can I keep the default `HandlerExceptionResolver`, but still apply my custom logic?

Comment: I stumbled on your thread with seemingly the same problem. ResponseEntityExceptionhandler wasn't cutting it. Somehow it didn't catch my 405, 406 and 415 exceptions. I tried catching these exceptions with @Exceptionhandler methods and even catching them in the generic exception method by writing conditionals for each Http status code. All of this seems very wrong from an architectural standpoint. Have you been able to find a satisfiable solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To provide a complete solution: it works just by extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, as that handles all the `spring-mvc` errors.
And the ones not handled can then be caught using `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)`.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(Exception ex) {
        MailService.send();
        Logger.logInSpecificWay();
        return ... custom exception 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you made this class an abstract class?

Comment: This will not catch all exceptions, some exception like when Spring is unable to build an object from the query params received or NOT_ACCEPTABLE messages are not going into this handler.
I don't really undertand why a @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class) do not catch all "spring error" but it is not enough.
Also, if you have a servlet error (before spring), it will also not be caught with this solution.

Comment: what is the usage of extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Answer (score 5):

Well, I was facing the same problem some time back and have tried several ways like extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` but all them were solving some problems but creating other ones.

Then I have decided to go with a custom solution which was also allowing me to send additional information and I have written below code

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNumberFormatException(NumberFormatException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getBody(BAD_REQUEST, ex, "Please enter a valid value"), new HttpHeaders(), BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getBody(BAD_REQUEST, ex, ex.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getBody(FORBIDDEN, ex, ex.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(getBody(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex, "Something Went Wrong"), new HttpHeaders(), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getBody(HttpStatus status, Exception ex, String message) {

        log.error(message, ex);

        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("message", message);
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("status", status.value());
        body.put("error", status.getReasonPhrase());
        body.put("exception", ex.toString());

        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        if (cause != null) {
            body.put("exceptionCause", ex.getCause().toString());
        }
        return body;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this is nice, I would not want to send `500` internal server error for all unhandled `Exception`. Eg if someone tries a `POST` on a `GET` method, spring by default would return a `405 Method not allowed`. But with an `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` I would swallow this standard handling of spring...

Comment: Try to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in your exception hander class.

Comment: In my case, having several specific handlers and one general "catch all" handler results in Spring always using the general one. In the code you provided, this would mean that the method "exception(Exception ex)" will always be called, regardless of the type of exception that was thrown. Did you configure something somewhere else?

Comment: @Alechan That can only happen if the only exception is being thrown is the object of Exception class or if your exception handler class MyExceptionHandler is not getting scanned by spring, only including this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create classes for exception handling in this way

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends BaseExceptionHandler {

}

public class BaseExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

}
```

Here **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** is provided by spring and override the several exception handler methods provided by it related to the requestMethodNotSupported,missingPathVariable,noHandlerFound,typeMismatch,asyncRequestTimeouts ....... with your own exception messages or error response objects and status codes

and have a method with **`@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)`** in MyExceptionHandler where the thrown exception comes finally if it doesn't have a matching handler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it creating a implementation of the interface `HandlerExceptionResolver` and removing the generic `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` from the generic handler method.
.

It works this way:

Spring will try to handle the exception calling `MyExceptionHandler` first, but it will fail to find a handler because the annotation was removed from the generic handler. Next it will try other implementations of the interface `HandlerExceptionResolver`. It will enter this generic implementation that just delegates to the original generic error handler.

After that, I need to convert the `ResponseEntity` response to `ModelAndView` using `MappingJackson2JsonView` because this interface expects a `ModelAndView` as return type.

```kotlin
@Component
class GenericErrorHandler(
    private val errorHandler: MyExceptionHandler,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) : HandlerExceptionResolver {

    override fun resolveException(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any, ex: Exception): ModelAndView? {
        // handle exception
        val responseEntity = errorHandler.handleUnexpectedException(ex)

        // prepare JSON view
        val jsonView = MappingJackson2JsonView(objectMapper)
        jsonView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true) // prevents creating the body key in the response json

        // prepare ModelAndView
        val mv = ModelAndView(jsonView, mapOf("body" to responseEntity.body))
        mv.status = responseEntity.statusCode
        mv.view = jsonView
        return mv
    }
}
```